# due to the addition of numbers the legend is half visible

Tags: r, 3d, plotrix

In legend have long text. This text is half visible after I add the numbers.
My code:

```
library(plotrix)
x <- c(16.6, 8.3, 11.7, 10.6,38.5,14.3)
lbls <- paste(x,"%") 
labels <- c("TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT", "TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT", "TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT", 
            "TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT", "TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT",
            "TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT")
colors<-c("#F69646","#B70000","#002060","#553C75","#632523","#00B0EF")
pie3D(x, labels=lbls,explode=0.1, height=0.05,  main='TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT', col=colors)
legend(0.75,1.1, labels, cex = 0.46,fill = colors)
```

[image: x]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add

par(xpd=TRUE)

between schedule and legend

Answer (score 0):

You need to tweak some of the legend parameters, especially `xjust` and `adj`:

```r
pie3D(x, labels = lbls, explode = 0.1, height = 0.05, 
      main = 'TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT', col = colors, mar = c(2, 4, 4, 4))
legend(0.75, 0.7, labels, cex = 0.46, fill = colors, xjust = 0.16, 
       inset = 0, adj = c(1, 0))
```

[image]